# How to re-shrink a bloated vhdx

Tags: windows-8, vhd, virtual-disk

I created a [Virtual Hard Disk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/hh831446.aspx) which expanded in filesize as I stored more stuff. But it doesn't reduce back in size as I delete stuff from it. As you can see

[image]

It only has 10G worth of content on the virtual drive, but its `.vhdx` file is still taking up the largest amount it has ever been (~3x).

Is there a way to shrink it back to the size of it's actual contents?

Comment: From my experience with Hyper-V, the minimum size you can shrink the virtual disk to seems to be based on the partition table inside the VHDX, so you might have to shrink partitions through Disk Management, then shrink the VHDX to minimum size. Afterwards, you can set the VHDX back to full size and resize the partition accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

[According to this link](http://windowsitpro.com/hyper-v/q-why-cant-i-shrink-virtual-hard-disk-file-my-desired-size), you should be able to use the resize-VHD cmdlet.

Give it a try, but backup your VHDX first :)